# I am not able to get the working of 'static' keyword. As I have read that static variables are common to all the instances(objects) of a class

Tags: java, static, webdriver

But in page object model why we are creating WebDriver reference as static in Base class, as we are not creating any object of Base Class.

static WebDriver driver;

We also use inheritance concept which means all properties of parent class will come to child class then what is the need of making this static variable.

Please help me to understand this concept of 'static' i.e when to use when not to use.

Comment: You use static when you want the field/method associated with the class instead of instances of that class. The use of inheritance does not change that.

Comment: "Common to all instances of a class" is misleading. In fact it is part of none of them. Static variables are associated with the class rather than with its instances (if any). As such they are not inheritable.

Answer (score 0):

> I have read that static variables are common to all the instances(objects) of a class

No, a variable marked `static` is not common to all instances. A static variable lives outside the objects, independent and separate. Effectively, a `static` variable in Java is like a [global variable](https://global%20variable) in [structured programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming), with the same risks of being abused.

You can think of `static` as meaning “non-object-oriented”. Using `static` is something of a hack, used only as a last resort to solve certain problems. Frequent use of `static` is an indicator of likely poor design or poor understanding of [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) technique.

> We also use inheritance concept which means all properties of parent class will come to child class then what is the need of making this static variable.

There is no need. The `static` variable is irrelevant to your inheritance hierarchy. Heck, the `static` variable is irrelevant to the class in which it is defined. Java has no other place to put a `static`, so the `static` vats are stuck there. Like a burr caught in your hair is not really a part of you as a person, so a `static` can be thought of as not really a part of a class in the sense of OOP.

Answer (score 0):

`static` properties of the `Class` are unique only for the class and inherited classes. The instantiated objects from the `Class` won't have an access to `static` properties.
Example:

```
class Parent {
  static get parentName() {
    return 'This is a static parent name and objects do not have access to it';
  }

  get lastName() {
    return 'This is common property and instance will have an access to it';
  }
}

const me = new Person();
console.log(me); // {lastName: 'This is common property and instance will have an access to it'}
console.log(me.name) // undefined

class Child extends Parent {

}

const myKid = new Child();
console.log(myKid.parentName); // undefined
console.log(myKid.lastName); // {lastName: 'This is common property and instance will have an access to it'}
```

`static` properties of the `Class` can only be used on the `Class` itself without instantiating.
Example:

```
console.log(Parent.parentName); // 'This is a static parent name and objects do not have access to it';
console.log(Child.parentName) // 'This is a static parent name and objects do not have access to it';
```